# Dissociate vertical alignment from adjacent cell contents

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, margins, cell

Good morning and a very good year to all of you,

My problem is this: when I insert a table (N2) into one of the cells of my base table (N1), the content of adjacent cells (on the same line) appears to align with the vertical center of table N2. As a result, the more the vertical dimension of table N2 increases, the more the margin above the content of the cells adjacent to N2 increases.

I have four times put you here the same table N1 with a table N2 whose vertical dimension increases each time. This way you can see how the content of the adjacent cells behave:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany,openbib, 11pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.5}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlongtables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=0mm,right=0mm,
bindingoffset=0mm, top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{9cm}p{18.1cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.5cm}}{} & Variables indépendantes & Résultats \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Verheij (1999)} & \rotatebox[origin=r]{-270} {Netherlands} &
1. Age \par
2. Gender \par
& \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{9cm}p{18.1cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.5cm}}{} & Variables indépendantes & Résultats \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Verheij (1999)} & \rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Netherlands} &
1. Age \par
2. Gender \par
& \begin{tabular}{p{4.10cm}p{4cm}}
    & Homeopathy in past 5 years \par Log-odds (SE) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{9cm}p{18.1cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.5cm}}{} & Variables indépendantes & Résultats \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Verheij (1999)} & \rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Netherlands} &
1. Age \par
2. Gender \par
& \begin{tabular}{p{4.10cm}p{4cm}}
    & Homeopathy in past 5 years \par Log-odds (SE) \\
    \hline
    Age & 0,3632 (0,11) \\
    \hline  
    Gender & 0,5837 (0,11) \\
    \hline
    Education & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{9cm}p{18.1cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.5cm}}{} & Variables indépendantes & Résultats \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Verheij (1999)} & \rotatebox[origin=r]{-270}{Netherlands} &
1. Age \par
2. Gender \par
& \begin{tabular}{p{4.10cm}p{4cm}}
    & Homeopathy in past 5 years \par Log-odds (SE) \\
    \hline
    Age & 0,3632 (0,11) \\
    \hline
    Gender & 0,5837 (0,11) \\
    \hline
    Education & \\
    \hline
    Insurance & \\
    \hline
    Place of residence (vsu vs. nu) & \\
    \hline
    Place of residence (su vs. nu) & \\
    \hline
    Place of residence (iu vs. nu) & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

My wish is to find the trick that allows to dissociate the vertical alignment of the contents of these different cells.
Does anyone see the trick?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you want `\begin{tabular}[t]{p{4.10cm}p{4cm}}` on the inner tables

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that is not it.

Comment: then you should clarify your question to say what "it" is, perhaps post an image of the current output annotated to show what you want to change, using `[t]` will prevent the alignment on the vertical centre that you describe in the question.

Comment: My apologies, in fact your solution works perfectly and fits exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I thought it didn't work... Thank you very much for your speed and efficiency!

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{4.10cm}p{4cm}}
```

on the inner tables will force them to align on the baseline of the top row, rather than their vertical centre.